# Restrict role to view own media

Tags: uploads, media-library

There are plenty of solutions for limiting access to view your own uploaded media but I was wondering if it was possible to limit media to a user role ( e.g. author's can see all other author's media files).

If not, could it be possible to see all user's uploaded media except the media uploaded by an admin?

Answer (score -1):

You can restrict users to seeing only their own uploaded media with this piece of code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Manage Your Media Only
Version: 0.1
*/

//Manage Your Media Only
function mymo_parse_query_useronly( $wp_query ) {
    if ( strpos( $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ], '/wp-admin/upload.php' ) !== false ) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'level_5' ) ) {
            global $current_user;
            $wp_query->set( 'author', $current_user->id );
        }
    }
}

add_filter('parse_query', 'mymo_parse_query_useronly' );
?>
```

Comment: User Levels were introduced in WordPress 1.5, they were replaced by Roles and Capabilities in WordPress 2.0, and were finaly **deprecated** in WordPress 3.0. Maybe you replace(edit/change your answer) it with the correct user role/capability?